# Validation in bootstrap modal dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, validation, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap 2.

Inside a form I have a button which opens a bootstrap modal dialog. Within the bootstrap modal dialog I have a select2 control, which I want to validate. i.e. I want at least one value in the select2 control. How do I validate the select2 control as a required field before the dialog is closed?

Note: closing the dialog doesn't submit the form.

Does Select2 have a mandatory/required property? Can the Save button of the dialog be linked to checking the select2 control?

I am using MVC4, bootstrap 2, razor.

Comment: Select2 is a plugin for manage a <select>,so, you have to set the 'required' to this <select>, no ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap modal component fire a `hide` event when closing.
You should register an handler to this event, make your validation, and prevent bubbling if needed.

For example:

```
$('#myModal').on('hide', function (evt) {
  var isValid = // make your validation
  if (!isValid) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    return false;
  }
});
```

Comment: Your trick with `preventDefault()` and `stopImmediatePropogation()` and `return false` helped me keep this event from rebinding all the time. I was doing a `console.log(evt)` and without that extra stuff, the first close click gave me one `evt` object, the second, two `evt` objects, third click, three `evt` objects, and so on. Your tweak fixed that for me.

Comment: I also now use `'hidden.bs.modal'` now instead of `'hide'` because I'm using Bootstrap 3.